# Magento2 : How to hide a Product from a specific Customer Group?

Tags: product, module, extensions, magento-2.1.3, customer-group

I want to create an extension that will hide a product from a specific customer group.

Comment: if you found any solution please attach

Comment: Try this one https://github.com/karliuka/m2.ProductAvailable, I'm not the owner of that github repo. Credits to the owner of that one. You can find the idea in there. Thanks

Comment: yes i see this module but i m looking for hide category and product @MazeStricks

Comment: please share more details about the issue

Comment: @MazeStricks 1. can u please confirm you want to hide product (or) price 
2. Do you want to hide the same product from the category listing page? 
could you please provide some details.

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: please test demo of mageants [restrict products by customer group](https://www.mageants.com/restrict-products-by-customer-group-for-magento-2.html) i think it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used an extension by Amasty to accomplish this. It's not free but it will do what you're looking for.

https://amasty.com/customer-group-catalog-for-magento-2.html